# Compare every element between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming that I have two dataframes:

```
# df1
+-----------------------+
| Name_1 |Age| Location |
+-----------------------+
| A    | 18  |    UK    |
| B    | 19  |    US    |
+-----------------------+

# df2
+-------------------------+
| Name_2 | Age | Location |
+-------------------------+
| A    | 18  |    US      |
| B    | 19  |    US      |
+-------------------------+
```

How can I compare all of the elements and get a dataframe with boolean values that indicate whether the corresponding values match?

The desired output would be:

```
# desired
+-----------------------+
| Name | Age  | Location|
+-----------------------+
| A    | True |  False  |
| B    | True |  True   |
+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If same number of rows and same columns names in both DataFrames create indices by `name` in both by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then compare:

```
df11 = df1.set_index('name')
df22 = df2.set_index('name')
df = (df11 == df22).reset_index()
```

EDIT: If different only columns for `index`:

```
df11 = df1.set_index('Name_1')
df22 = df2.set_index('Name_2')
df = (df11 == df22).reset_index()
print (df)
  Name_1   Age  Location
0      A  True     False
1      B  True      True
```

If possible different another columns, but length of columns is still same and also length of index is necessary set same columns names in both - e.g. `df22 columns` by `df11 columns`:

```
print (df1)
  Name_1  Age1 Location1
0      A    18        UK
1      B    19        US

print (df2)
  Name_2  Age2 Location2
0      A    18        US
1      B    19        US

df11 = df1.set_index('Name_1')
df22 = df2.set_index('Name_2')
df22.columns = df11.columns
df = (df11 == df22).reset_index()
print (df)
  Name_1  Age1  Location1
0      A  True      False
1      B  True       True
```

Comment: if you are using `tabulate` and if I may assume `Name` is already the index, you probably only need `df11==df22`

Comment: @eliu - then `df1 == df2`

Comment: Would this work even if I have different column names? See my updated question.